# Power monitor from USB

Tags: power-supply, usb

What are the possibilities of powering a computer monitor from USB, either with one or more ports? And what would happen if the monitor does not get enough power?

For example, the T2236MSC-B2 monitor from iiYama. The specs say that it typically uses 23 watts. I have read different things over power over a USB port, yet I am not really able to draw a conclusion.

Comment: USB2 is normally 2.5W. USB3 "power delivery" can manage 20V 5A = 100W, so that should work. Most of the power is for the backlight.

Comment: Do you have any sources that would help with rewiring the device to be powered from USB?

Answer (score 0):

The monitor you quote [specifies](http://www.iiyama.com/gl_en/products/prolite-t2236msc-2/) "Power supply AC 100 - 240 V, 50 / 60 Hz," so you would be looking to convert the USB power to mains-voltage AC or to convert it to whatever the internal supply generates (which would involve wiring into it internally). Probably not the best idea.

USB-powered monitors are available; if there is not enough power then either the display will be limited in its brightness or simply not work.